# java creating an object in subclass

Tags: java, inheritance

Having trouble creating an author object in the Book class.This is indeed Homework, I have came up with all the methods on my own and have been staring at this assignment for 2 hours now. any tips hints will be appreciated. I believe I am only allowed this one Author constructor with 3 parameters otherwise I would just have made an Author constructor with no arguments and the problem would be gone.

```
public class Author {

    protected String name;
    protected String email;
    protected char gender;

    public Author(String name, String email, char gender)
    {
        this.name = name;
        this.email = email;
        this.gender = gender;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public String getEmail()
    {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email)
    {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public char getGener()
    {
        return gender;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return ( name + "(" + gender + ")@" + email);
    }


}

public class Book extends Author{

    private String name;
    private Author author;
    private double price;
    private int qtyInStock = 0;

    public Book(String name, Author author,Double price)
    {
        this.author = new author;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;

    }

    public Book(String name, Author author, double price, int qtyInStock)
    {

        this.name = name;
        this.author = author;
        this.price = price;
        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
    }

    public String getName()
    {
        return name;
    }

    public Author getAuthor()
    {
        return author;
    }

    public double getPrice()
    {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(double price)
    {
        this.price = price;
    }

    public int getQtyInStock()
    {
        return qtyInStock;
    }

    public void setQtyInStock(int qtyInStock)
    {
        this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
    }

    public String toString()
    {
        return (name + " by " + author + "(" + super.gender + ")at" + super.email);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems strange that `Book extends Author`. A `Book` is not an `Author`.

I think what you want to do is create a `Book` object that has an `Author`, but you are already passing in an `Author` to your `Book` constructor, so what is the problem?

```
class Book {
    public Book(String title, Author author) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
    }
}
```

If you're wondering how to create the `Author`, just create it before you pass it to the `Book`.

```
Author author = new Author("bob", "bob@email.com", 'm');
Book book = new Book("some title", author);
```

Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

It should be `this.author = author;` without the `new` keyword.

You are assigning the `Author` object in the constructor, not creating new one.

By the way, `Book` inherits from `Author` which means it already has the `Author` functionality. You don't have to save it as member.

Answer (score 0):

You are inheriting `Author` in `Book`, inheritance is `is a relationship`, means `Book is a Author` which is not true in real world scenario , you need `has a relation` which makes sense , that `Book has a Author`.

So don't extend author in Book , keep a field of author in it as you have already did. Change you design.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple mistakes in your code:

1. as @Guy said, you need to assign the author with `this.author = author`, without the `new` keyword.
2. you are shadowing the name variable from the `Author` class by also including a variable with the same name in the `Book` class. Remove that variable and the getter and setter methods from the `Book` class.
3. You don´t have a no parameter constructor, so you have to call the parent constructor in your `Book` class by calling `super(name, email, gender);`.

Answer (score 0):

you should replace new author with author, also when you call the constructor of a sub Type, the Parent class's default constructor is invoked by default. so you need to specify a default constructor in your parent class, or to prevent this explicitly call your parametric constructor of parent class in the child class constructor .

Answer (score 0):

Besides changing to`this.author = author`. 
You also need to add `super(name, name, 'M');` to the two constructors of the `Book` class.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Book extends Author{

private String name;
//private final String email;
// private char gender;
private Author author;// = new Author(name,super.email,super.gender);
private double price;
private int qtyInStock = 0;

public Book(String name, Author author,double price)
{
    //super();
    this.author = author;// new Author(name,super.email,super.gender);
    super.name = author.getName();
    super.gender = author.getGender();
    super.email = author.getEmail();
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;

}

public Book(String name, Author author, double price, int qtyInStock)
{
    this.author = author;
    super.name = author.getName();
    super.gender = author.getGender();
    super.email = author.getEmail();
    this.name = name;
    this.price = price;
    this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
}

public String getName()
{
    return name;
}

public Author getAuthor()
{
    return author;
}

public double getPrice()
{
    return price;
}

public void setPrice(double price)
{
    this.price = price;
}

public int getQtyInStock()
{
    return qtyInStock;
}

public void setQtyInStock(int qtyInStock)
{
    this.qtyInStock = qtyInStock;
}

public String toString()
{
    return (super.name + " by " + this.name + "(" + super.gender + ")at" + super.email);
}
```

also added this to the author class

```
 public Author()
{

}
```